# Would a package downloaded by NPM be the same as the local file in my case?

Tags: jquery, npm

In my project previous developers put `jQuery` in the local environment, and minified version 3.1.1 has been kept since 2 years ago. I'm trying to manage it using NPM. So more senior devs were trying to prevent me from upgrading `jQuery` to latest version using NPM saying the upgrade may break stuff. Fine, I'll keep the current version then. But I'd like to use NPM to manage it. Then they were trying to prevent me from using NPM due to previous Devs may have touched `jQuery` source code.

So here is the question: now there are 3 things about `jQuery` for me:

1. the minified `jQuery 3.1.1` exists in the local file
2. minified `jQuery 3.1.1` downloaded by NPM
3. `jQuery` restored in pipeline

Are they the same? I've compared 1 and 2 use a code comparison tool and they are exactly the same, meaning in this case 1 has not been touched by previous dev. If this is the case, can I say the jQuery restored in pipeline is also the same as 1 and 2? If they are the same, does it mean what other dev said was wrong and jQuery is safe to be managed by NPM?

Comment: Problem is, this dev has left the company and there is no way to find out whether he has touched the source code. My point was, despite what other devs said, if I can prove 1 and 2 are exactly the same, does this mean 3 would also be the same? Otherwise the website would behave differently on product and local?

Comment: `if I can prove 1 and 2 are exactly the same, does this mean 3 would also be the same?` Yes it does. You can use a file diff checker to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think if the code comparison tool doesn't find any changes they are the same.
The minified jQuery 3.1.1 should be the same in NPM as in normal .min download.

So i think the dev was wrong in this case.